# Accessing API to download data without admin rights on Machine

Tags: javascript, python, windows, powershell, api

I want to trial accessing an API without admin rights for my work machine - due to corporate setting.
I can't use Python as there is restricted access to the web.
It is possible to build a macro in excel, however this is not a preferred method.

Can you recommend any path forward.

An example API Endpoint URL: https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json 
Documentation of API: https://github.com/alphagov/calendars/blob/master/README.md

Comment: "I can't use Python as there is restricted access to the web." <-- sounds like you need to ask your local helpdesk for an exception then - if it's blocked at the network level, then it doesn't really matter which scripting language you pick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use powershell using the `Invoke-Restmethod` command, for example:

```
$data = Invoke-RestMethod https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json
$data.'england-and-wales'.events
```

This returns a long list of the events in the "England and Wales" region

| title | date | notes | bunting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New Year’s Day | 2016-01-01 |  | True |
| Good Friday | 2016-03-25 |  | False |
| Easter Monday | 2016-03-28 |  | True |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

After that you can manipulate the data however you want, its quite simple once you get the hang of it :)